# Skip Shipping method in Checkout

Tags: checkout, shipping, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout

Is there any way(Configuration setting or from xml) to skip Shipping method block in checkout.

Without any customization or installing any extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it without any configuration or customization is to create virtual or downloadable products and Magento will automatically skip shipping method. this is what product type virutal is for.

Comment: Hello Siddharth, Thanks for your response. I am using complex products(Bundle, Configurable and Grouped).

Comment: Refer to this extension then http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-hide-shipping-method-on-magento-frontend-but-leave-it-on-in-admin-area/